# Cheap material for stiff, thick, lightweight, insulating walls?

Tags: walls, insulation, materials

I want to construct a large water tank. The walls need to be

- fairly thick (several centimetres)
- very stiff (they will be decoratively plastered inside and out and the plaster should not crack)
- lightweight (on the order of 2m x 2m sections to be arranged by hand)
- effective insulators (the water is hot)
- inexpensive
- ideally, environmentally friendly

What should I use?

Comment: How large is "large"?

Comment: You forgot “strong” too.

Comment: why would you plaster the inside of a water tank?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 2m sides, as the question said.

Comment: @LeeSam To support a mass of water in a 2m box, as the question said.

Comment: @jsotola Have you ever seen a swimming pool?

Comment: This is either a product recommendation request or too broad, as a single product won't meet these criteria. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Get a stainless steel tank and then bond / glue good insulation to the outside surface.

Then cover the insulation with a suitable covering to paint as necessary.